# Excel Online API c#

Tags: c#, excel, api, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Как из c# приложения получить доступ к содержимому электронной таблицы которая хранится на OneDrive? Есть ли у Excel Online аналог API как у Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: А Office Interop чем вас не устраивает?

Comment: @VladD может тем что с ним *тяжело* работать? у меня так и не получилось освободить память выделенную под *созданные* объекты(в процессах остаются экземпляры excel, word), те рецепты которые я находил в инете не помогали, хотя возможно я просто не умею его *готовить*

Comment: @Bald: `ReleaseComObject` или там `FinalReleaseComObject` (если вы на 100% уверены, что на объект точно нет внутренних ссылок) разве не работал?

Comment: @VladD, Вы уверены что Office Interop дает возможность редактировать документ Excel Online (https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx)?

Comment: Посмотрите, может быть это оно: https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/10937